# Weight Calculation Algorithm Based on different parameters?

Tags: algorithm

I am Trying to figure out the algorithm which can predict the best possible option based on some parameters.

For E.g:- 
A has Parameters as 1,2,3
B has Parameters as 4,5,6
So based on the Parameters Values can we Figure out or do we have predefined algorithm for the Weight calculation of A and B which can help us to predict the 
which is Better.

Summary :- i am looking for a algorithm to calculate the weights of a node , based on Some parameters.

Comment: Please provide a more detailed explanation of what you are trying to achieve, as the question is not descriptive enough.

Comment: How do we decide the next move on game theory.
We have some parameters based on which we took some decision , correct ?
How do we manipulate the parameters ?

Comment: Please provide an example of the input and the desired output of such a hypothetical algorithm.